# How to write test class for auto-generated JIT Class SSO

Tags: apex, unit-test, class, single-sign-on

```
private void handleUser(boolean create, User u, Map<String, String> attributes,String federationIdentifier, boolean isStandard)
```

I am just creating a user in SSO JIT using this **handleuser** method.

```
Values i can pass/ assign is
Create = true; 
user u= new user(); 
isStandard=true; 
federationIdentifier ='abc@gmail.com';

how to use Map<String, String> attributes ??
```

Example :

```
 if(attributes.containsKey('User.Email')) {
            u.Email = attributes.get('User.Email');
            u.Username = attributes.get('User.email');
           system.debug('username'+u.Username);
        }
        if(attributes.containsKey('User.FirstName')) {
            u.FirstName = attributes.get('User.FirstName');
        }
```

**How do I cover this attributes.get('User.Email')**

this is what I have tried ??

```
 User user = new User();
 user.FirstName = 'Test';
 user.LastName = 'Name';
 user.CompanyName = 'IT Test Company';
 user.MobilePhone = '123-456-7890';
 user.Username = 'testUser-@test.com';
 user.Email = 'testUser-@test.com';
 user.Alias = 'test';
 user.CommunityNickname = 'test1';
 user.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York';
 user.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
 user.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
 user.ProfileId = prof.Id;
 user.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'; user.Street = '123 Test St';
 user.City = 'Testcity';
 user.State = 'va'; user.PostalCode = '23223';
 user.Country = 'USA';

insert user;

    System.runAs(user) {
System.debug('Current User: '
     + UserInfo.getUserName());  }
```

Comment: You put it in your map? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Isn't it easier to just use sObject.put() to handle that Map <String, String> ?

Comment: I have edited the post what i have tried , SFDCFOX and MKORMAN this is what I have tried. Please, can you guide me what should I do next?